# Is it possible to make an object "Read Only" to a method

Tags: java, object, reference

If an object reference is passed to a method, is it possible to make the object "Read Only" to the method?

Comment: there is an old, but still good resource: http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~boyland/papers/readonly-talk.pdf

Comment: what about storing a reference to the object, clone it and compare from time to time if nothing changed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not strictly speaking. That is, a reference that can mutate an object can not be turned into a reference that can not mutate an object. Also, there is not way to express that a type is immutable or mutable, other than using conventions.

The only feature that ensure some form of immutability would be `final` fields - once written they can not be modified.

That said, there are ways to design classes so that **unwanted mutation are prevented**. Here are some techniques:

- *[Defensive Copying](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2)*. Pass a copy of the object, so that if it is mutated it doesn't break your internal invariants.
- Use *access modifiers* and/or *interface* to expose only read-only methods. You can use access modifieres (`public`/`private`/`protected`), possibly combined with interface, so that only certain methods are visible to the other object. If the methods that are exposed are read-only by nature, you are safe.
- Make your object *immutable by default*. Any operation on the object returns actually a copy of the object.

Also, note that the API in the SDK have sometimes methods that return an immutable version of an object, e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableList`. An attempt to mutate an immutable list will throw an exception. This does not enforce immutability statically (at compile-time with the static type system), but is is a cheap and effective way to enforce it dynamically (at run-time).

There has been many research proposals of Java extension to better control of aliasing, and accessibility. For instance, addition of a `readonly` keyword. None of them is as far as I know planned for inclusion in future version of Java. You can have a look at these pointers if you're interested:

- [Why We Should Not Add ''Read-Only'' to Java (yet)](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIABEBYwAA&url=http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~boyland/papers/readonly-talk.pdf&ei=JrKrT5f7B8-i-ga_5L2eCg&usg=AFQjCNGk4pS8x5s38IVL96D9WpBN4fMUig) -- it lists and compare most of the proposals
- [The Checker Framework: Custom pluggable types for Java](https://checkerframework.org/manual/) -- a non intrusive way to extend the type system, notably with immutable types.

The Checker Framework is very interesting. In the Checker Framework, look at Generic Universe Types checker, IGJ immutability checker, and Javari immutability checker. The framework works using annotations, so it is not intrusive.

Comment: I think if we have final field called list which is an arraylist of Custom objects and that custom object's class has setter methods in it, then we can use list.get(0).setName() or something like that to modify the final field as well, so final fields are also not strictly unmodifiable, it just means "list" field is stuck with this arrayList forever. Let me know if my understanding is not right

Comment: Even returning a clone of the object is not foolproof, if we think about it

Answer (score 8):

No, not without decorating, compositing, cloning, etc.

Answer (score 8):

There's no general mechanism for that. You'll need to write special-case code to achieve it, like writing an immutable wrapper (see `Collections.unmodifiableList`).

Comment: This example is of practical use.

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve a similar thing in most cases by cloning the `Object` as the first statement of the method, such as this...

```
public void readOnlyMethod(Object test){
    test = test.clone();
    // other code here
}
```

So if you called `readOnlyMethod()` and pass in any `Object`, a clone of the `Object` will be taken. The clone uses the same name as the parameter of the method, so there's no risk of accidentally changing the original `Object`.

Comment: This requires the object to actually implement `clone` properly and, since this is a f*ed-up API, modern classes rarely bother with it.

Comment: Correct. However, I would hope that most core Java classes should implement `clone()` properly, so this will cover *most* situations. Its probably about as close as you're going to get for a read-only parameter

Comment: How about `Collections.unmodifiableList` -- that's from the core API (no cloning).

Comment: I'm not pretending that everything is wonderful and perfect by using `clone()`, I'm just presenting this as a possibility that should be considered.

Comment: Yes, cloning is definitely worth considering. My real point was that it is more typical today to write a custom `copyOf`-kind of method, or a copy-constructor, and avoid `clone` as the concrete mechanism to use.

Answer (score 4):

making it implement a interface which has only read only methods (no setter methods) this gives a copy of an object (road-only copy) and returning the read only instance of interface instead of returning the instance of an object itself

Answer (score 3):

No. But you could try to clone the object before passing it, so any changes made by the method won't affect the original object.

Answer (score 1):

You could define all parameters of the objects as `final` but that makes the object read only to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your real question is about avoiding escape references.

As pointed out in some answers to extract an Interface from class and expose only get methods. It will prevent modification by accident but it is again not a foolproof solution to avoid above problem.

Consider below example:

**Customer.java:**

```
public class Customer implements CustomerReadOnly {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.list.add("First");
        this.list.add("Second");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

**CustomerReadOnly.java:**

```
public interface CustomerReadOnly {

    String getName();

    ArrayList<String> getList();

}
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerReadOnly c1 = new Customer("John");

        System.out.println("printing list of class before modification");
        for(String s : c1.getList()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        ArrayList<String> list = c1.getList();
        list.set(0, "Not first");

        System.out.println("printing list created here");
        for(String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.out.println("printing list of class after modification");
        for(String s : c1.getList()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
printing list of class before modification
First
Second
printing list created here
Not first
Second
printing list of class after modification
Not first
Second
```

So, as you can see extracting interface and exposing only get methods works only if you don't have any mutable member variable.

If you have a collection as a member variable whose reference you don't want to get escape from class, you can use `Collections.unmodifiableList()` as pointed out in ewernli's answer.

With this no external code can modify the underlying collection and your data is fully read only.

But again when it comes to custom objects for doing the same, I am aware of the Interface method only as well which can prevent modification by accident but not sure about the foolproof way to avoid reference escape.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want the rule enforced. If you are working collaboratively on a project, use `final` with a comment telling the next person they are not meant to modify this value.  Otherwise wouldn't you simply write the method to *not* touch the object?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    cantTouchThis("Cant touch this");
}

/**
 * 
 * @param value - break it down
 */
public static void cantTouchThis(final String value) {
    System.out.println("Value: " + value);
    value = "Nah nah nah nah"; //Compile time error
}
```

So specifically to this method, the value will never be written to, and it is enforced at compile time making the solution extremely robust.  Outside the scope of this method, the object remains unaltered without having to create any sort of wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isExecuteWriteQueue = false;
public boolean isWriting(){
    final boolean b = isExecuteWriteQueue;
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on ewernli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10533902/6893866)...

If you own the classes, you can use read-only interfaces so that methods using a read-only reference of the object can only get read-only copies of the children; while the main class returns the writable versions.

example

```
public interface ReadOnlyA {
    public ReadOnlyA getA();
}

public class A implements ReadOnlyA {
    @Override
    public A getA() {
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] cheese) {
        ReadOnlyA test= new A();
        ReadOnlyA b1 = test.getA();
        A b2 = test.getA(); //compile error
    }
}
```

---

If you don't own the classes, you could extend the class, overriding the setters to throw an error or no-op, and use separate setters. This would effectively make the base class reference the read-only one, however this can easily lead to confusion and hard to understand bugs, so make sure it is well documented.